# Xui.js .children() alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, xui

What's the xui.js (or pure javascript if necessary) alternative for jQuery's `.children()`.

To be more specific, I'm trying to get the child of `$x(this)` but `$x(this).children('p')` doesn't work (as in, it doesn't seem to exist in the library. It's not recognized according to Firebug nor is it in the xuijs docs).

Comment: "Does not work" provides little information. Explain how the problem manifests itself.

Comment: As in, it doesn't exist. The docs show know such function, and firebug confirms it by not recognizing the function. I don't think it's part of the library.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about that library, but if you have the native DOM element, the native JS could look like this:

```
[].filter.call(this.children, function(el, i) { 
    return el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'p'; 
});
```

If you're supporting legacy browsers, you can get a shim for `Array.prototype.filter` from MDN.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility

---

And you can easily make a reusable function too.

```
function children(elem, s) {
    return [].filter.call(elem.children, function(el, i) { 
        return el.nodeType === 1 && (!s || el.nodeName.toLowerCase() === s); 
    });
}
```

---

```
children(this, 'p');
```

It only filters by tag name, but it would be simple to extend it.